# Delphi OleVariant to array of string from COM Library

Tags: string, delphi, com, variant, safearray

I have Delphi 2006 client application. This client recieves an Olevariant type data from COM server. The function is:

```
procedure OnLimitsChanged(var SymbolsChanged: {??PSafeArray}OleVariant);
```

This function returns an array of string. I can´t read OleVariant type data from delphi.

From Excel VBA it´s working:

```
Private Sub g_Realtime_OnLimitsChanged(SymbolsChanged() As String)
    Dim i%
    Dim Salir As Boolean
    If UBound(SymbolsChanged) <> -1 Then
        i = 0: Salir = False
        While Not Salir
            If SymbolsChanged(i) = Simbolo Then
                LlamarALimites
                Salir = True
            Else
                i = i + 1
                If i > UBound(SymbolsChanged) Then Salir = True
            End If
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to convert OleVariant to Psafearray...

```
procedure TfmConfiguracion.RecibirNuevosTicks(ASender: TObject;
  var ArrayTicks : Olevariant);    
var 
  Data : pSafeArray;
  i,iLow, iHigh : Integer;  
  value : wideString;
begin
  Data:=PSafeArray(TVarData(ArrayTicks).VArray);
  SafeArrayGetLBound(Data,1,iLow);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(Data,1,iHigh);
  for i:=iLow to iHigh do
  begin
    SafeArrayGetElement(Data,i,Value);
    Showmessage(Value);
  end;
```

But I recieve an except in this line:

```
 SafeArrayGetLBound(Data,1,iLow);
```

> Debugger Fault Notification
>   Project ... faulted with message: ' access violation at 0x751de18c: read of address 0xabababab'. Process Stopper. Use Step or Run to continue

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're assuming that `ArrayTicks` is an array but perhaps it's not.

Comment: Why is `ArrayTicks` being passed by `var`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This function is a third-party com library. They told me that function returns an array of string (CStringArray to Safearray).

Answer (score 5):

The RTL has a `VarArrayAsPSafeArray()` function for extracting a `PSafeArray` correctly from an `(Ole)Variant`:

```
procedure TfmConfiguracion.RecibirNuevosTicks(ASender: TObject; var ArrayTicks : OleVariant);    
var 
  Data : PVarArray; // RTL's version of PSafeArray
  //...
begin
  Data := VarArrayAsPSafeArray(ArrayTicks);
  //...
end;
```

If the `(Ole)Variant` does not contain an array, an exception will be raised.  Or you can use `VarIsArray()` to check it manually:

```
procedure TfmConfiguracion.RecibirNuevosTicks(ASender: TObject; var ArrayTicks : OleVariant);    
var 
  Data : PVarArray;
  //...
begin
  if not VarIsArray(ArrayTicks) then Exit;
  Data := VarArrayAsPSafeArray(ArrayTicks);
  //...
end;
```

That being said, `(Ole)Variant` has build-in support for accessing `PSafeArray` element data, so you don't really need to resort to accessing `PSafeArray` directly (unless you want an extra performance boost, in which case you need to validate the `PSafeArray` yourself before you access its data):

```
procedure TfmConfiguracion.RecibirNuevosTicks(ASender: TObject; var ArrayTicks : Olevariant);    
var 
  i : Integer;  
  value : String;
begin
  if not VarIsArray(ArrayTicks) then Exit;
  for i := VarArrayLowBound(ArrayTicks, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(ArrayTicks, 1) do
  begin
    Value := ArrayTicks[i];
    ShowMessage(Value);
  end;
```

Comment: `if not VarIsArray(ArrayTicks) then Exit; Data := VarArrayAsPSafeArray(ArrayTicks);`  **Incompatibles types: ‘PsafeArray’ and ‘PVarArray’**

Comment: **Exception in this line**  `for i := VarArrayLowBound(ArrayTicks,1) to VarArrayHighBound(ArrayTicks,1) do`    Debugger Fault Notification: Project … Faulted with message: access violation at 0x76cde18c: read of address 0xad33a794. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue

Comment: @EFD: I corrected the "incompatible types" error. As for the exception, I have no clue. If `VarIsArray()` is not crashing, and is returning True, then clearly the `OleVariant` holds a valid array. This kind of code works fine for me when I try it, so something else is going on with your case.

Answer (score 3):

The RTL has the [function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Variants.VarArrayAsPSafeArray) let access a `Varant` array as a `SAFEARRAY`:

```
function VarArrayAsPSafeArray(const V: Variant): PSafeArray;
```

I wanted to document how to do the reverse.

### Variant is a structure

In Delphi a `Variant` is an opaque blob. But internally it is really the `TVarData` structure (aka the Windows [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure). A variant can hold different types of data. You indicate which type through the `VType` member. The value of the `VType` member tells you how to interpret the rest of the structure:

**a 32-bit Integer (`VT_I4`)**

- **Variant**

  - `VType: Word = VT_I4;` //3
  - `VInteger: Integer;`

**a IUnknown interface (`VT_UNKNOWN`)**

- **Variant**

  - `VType: Word = VT_UNKNOWN;` //13
  - `VUnknown: Pointer;` //actually IUnknown

**an BSTR (aka WideString in Delphi)**

- **Variant**

  - `VType: Word = VT_BSTR;` //8
  - `VOleStr: PWideChar;`

In the case that the variant is a SAFEARRAY of 32-bit integers:

- **Variant**

  - `VType:  Word = (VT_ARRAY or VT_I4);`
  - `VArray: PVarArray;`

And then `VArray` points to a `SAFEARRAY` strucuture:

- **Variant**

  - `VType:  Word = (VT_ARRAY or VT_I4);`
  - `VArray: PVarArray;`

    - `cDims: Word;`
    - `fFeatures: Word;`
    - `cbElements: LongWord;`
    - `cLocks: LongWord;`
    - `pvData: Pointer;`
    - `rgsabound: array[0..0] of TSafeArrayBound;`

### What if we start with a SAFEARRAY

There are times, particularly when interacting with COM or .NET that you:

- have to supply a `PSafeArray`,
- or are given a `PSafeArray`.

You can construct a `SafeArray` easily enough, if you use Delphi's functions to create a *variant array*. Delphi does the heavy lifting to creating the underlying SafeArray that your "variant array" actually is.

But we want to go the other way; we are given a `PSafeArray`, and we want to wrap it up inside a Delphi **Variant** variable, so that it handles all the ugliness and lifetime.

```
assemblies: PSafeArray;

assemblies := DefaultAppDomain.GetAssemblies;
```

How can we deal with this pointer to a `SAFEARRAY`?

```
function PSafeArrayToVariant(psa: PSafeArray): OleVariant;
begin
   TVarData(v).VType = (VT_ARRAY or VT_xxxx); 
   TVarData(v).VArray := PVarArray(psa);
end;
```

except we need to know what the SafeArray contains; we need to fill in the **VT_xxxx** in the above code.

Fortunately, one of the members of the SAFEARRAY structure tells what VType the members of the array are:

- `fFeatures: Word;`

  - **FADF_BSTR**: It is an array of BSTRs (`VT_BSTR`)
  - **FADF_UNKNOWN**: It is an array of IUnknown (`VT_UNKNOWN`)
  - **FADF_DISPATCH**: It is an array of IDispatch (`VT_DISPATCH`)
  - **FADF_VARIANT**: It is an array of Variants (`VT_VARIANT`)
  - **FADF_HAVEVARTYPE**: You can get the type using [**SafeArrayGetVartype**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221446.aspx)

### Final function

```
function SafeArrayGetVartype(psa: PSafeArray): TVarType; safecall; external 'OleAut32.dll';

function PSafeArrayToVariant(psa: PSafeArray): OleVariant;
var
    features: Word;
    vt: TVarType;
const
    FADF_HAVEVARTYPE = $80;
begin
    features := psa^.fFeatures;
    if (features and FADF_UNKNOWN) = FADF_UNKNOWN then
        vt := VT_UNKNOWN
    else if (features and FADF_DISPATCH) = FADF_DISPATCH then
        vt := VT_DISPATCH
    else if (features and FADF_VARIANT) = FADF_VARIANT then
        vt := VT_VARIANT
    else if (features and FADF_BSTR) <> 0 then
        vt := VT_BSTR
    else if (features and FADF_HAVEVARTYPE) <> 0 then
        vt := SafeArrayGetVartype(psa)
    else
        vt := VT_UI4; //assume 4 bytes of *something*

    TVarData(Result).VType := VT_ARRAY or vt;
    TVarData(Result).VArray := PVarArray(psa);
end;
```

Comment: The declaration for SafeArrayGetvartype seems to have been removed from Delphi?

Comment: @DaveNottage I don't know if it ever existed in Delphi, but it isn't a Delphi function - it's a Windows API function [**SafeArrayGetVarType**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221446.aspx). The code includes the declaration to let you call it (`function blah blah blah external 'OleAut32.dll;`)